# How to Set Bounds of JTable while Set Layout is Null?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, null-layout-manager

In my

```
public UI(){

I have JTextField,JButtons and labels
I have also setLayout(null);

}
```

Now I'm Trying to create a JTable

```
JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);
```

But it wont display until I take out setLayout

For all the buttons,text boxes and labels I have `setBounds();`

How can I display the JTable while the setLayout is Null?

Comment: Please examine [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Areyou adding it to a JScrollPane?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes `con.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.SOUTH);`

Comment: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - that's the exclusive responsibility of the LayoutManager. So the question is moot ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `null` Layout, instead use `LayoutManagers`. Java created for you amazing layouts, you just have to use it, and let the layout do your job instead of hard working of calculating the position and size.

That's my answer, but if you insist of using it, just call `setBounds(x,y,width,height)` method for the `JTable`.
But again, don't use absolute positioning(`null` Layout).

```
//....
JScrollPane scrol = new JScrollPane(table);
scrol.setBounds(table.getBounds());
//....
```

Comment: @mKorbel: Yes, you're right, the header won't show up unill adding it to `JScrollPane` and set the bounds of scrollPane too.

Comment: I Tried doing this but still displayed nothing `table.setBounds(10,10,100,100);`

Comment: @Shiv Chand and before anything here to solve the conflict in your posts here `1. How can I display the JTable while the setLayout is Null?` v.s. `2. con.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.SOUTH);`, because only one of ways can to shows your JTable, notice JTable can't be empty for `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, otherwise there is created rectangle of 10 x 10 pixels

Comment: @ShivChand: listen to mLorbel's advice, and I edited the post.

Comment: @Caffè not, please to amend code posted here with setPreferredScrollableViewportSize